# Deploying code via GitHub

Tags: configuration, magento2.2.6, github

Due to the security reasons, we want to deploy the changes in code with GitHub. I can see that we can only change the code via GitHub.

> Is it possible to change the admin configuration as well via GitHub?

Or we can only do this via admin panel.

Looking for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change admin configuration with the code you need to create UpgradeData scripts for set of changes. This way each time code is deployed and `setup:upgrade` command is run, changes will be reflected in the database, in the admin panel.

A lot of configuration is default, handled in `config.xml` file. You can also create your own module with config.xml file where you can specify inital configuration. Just make sure your module is loaded after core modules or 3rd party modules. This way configuration in `My/Module/etc/config.xml` will overwrite default settings.

However, if configuration is already stored in the database, you should use UpgradeData scripts where you can set system configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I will try to do it.